# Phase transition in 2D Heisenberg model

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition

When we study the two-dimensional isotropic Heisenberg Model using Mean Field Theory or by Monte Carlo simulation we observe a phase transition at a temperature not equal to zero. This is opposed to Mermin Wagner theorem.
Interestingly this ordering happens only in z direction. Can anybody explain why we observe such a transition?

Comment: @JamalS OP is not asking about Ising model, but the isotropic Heisenberg. From mentioning the z direction I conclude that it is 2D as well, as required.

Comment: Are you working in $3d$ or $2d$?

Comment: BTW...mean field is neglecting fluctuations (check also local mean field), MC is problematic with spin wave excitations.

Comment: I am working 2d.
I understand MFT is ignoring fluctuations but why is preffering z direction specifically?

Comment: Then this is the so-called XY model, if I understand correctly. MFT is not good in $2d$, and the ordering you are witnessing must be a simulation artifact. There is no phase transition in the XY model, except for the BKT transition.

Comment: How is it XY model if we are taking into account Sz-Sz interactions also?

Answer (score 3):

If you simulate with angles you shouldn't take theta and phi uniform random numbers. In here

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

explained why. If you take random theta and phi uniformly, you oversampled in poles and your spins are a lot more up an down (like Ising).

Comment: Interesting info, thanks for sharing!